# Is this J. R. Dobbs on the picture at Nedry's desk?

Tags: reference, jurassic-park

So, some of you may have heard of this incredibly awesome website:

http://gizmodo.com/relive-jurassic-parks-iconic-hacking-scene-right-from-1535139292

which allows you to relive the classic scene from Jurassic Park. In that scene, you can clearly see something which I have noticed before - there is a picture of a person taped to Nedry's terminal smoking a pipe. I have always thought this was [J.R. Dobbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._R._%22Bob%22_Dobbs) for two reasons:

1. He's a similar looking guy
2. More importantly, J.R. Dobbs is the (fictional) author of "*The Church of the Subgenius*" and a big proponent of the concept of "Slack" (achieving your goals without working too hard). Now, "Slack" is the root for the namesake of "Slackware", which it the oldest current *Linux* distribution around. See the connection?

I have always held this to be an intrinsically obvious Easter Egg, but actually when you look closely, the resemblance to J.R. Dobbs is only passing. Can someone confirm or deny my suspicion? If it is not Dobbs, who is the mysterious man on Nedry's computer?

Comment: [IMDB trivia](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107290/trivia?item=tr0754366)

Comment: Praise "Bob" and Hail Eris! (Even thought that's Rob and not "Bob.")

Comment: What do you think is the meaning of the post it? "Beginning of Baby Boom." Next to a picture of an explosion with the word "boom" stuck on a picture of this guy's face. What's this about, and what's the connection to the rest of the movie?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[image: JRO]

That's a picture of [**J. Robert Oppenheimer**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._Robert_Oppenheimer), one of the *fathers of the atomic bomb* ([Manhattan Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_Project)).

- Notice the left post-it note? It shows a mushroom cloud and the word "BOOM".

[image: JRO] <sup>[[Source](http://www.magnumphotos.com/C.aspx?VP3=SearchDetail&VBID=2K1HZO3RRW0CQ&PN=45&IID=2S5RYD9OB1R)]</sup>

Comment: Oh no, I thought it was a tree! Hahahah! Well, well done my friend.

Comment: I thought the mushroom cloud was a tree also. The shot appears so quickly and I was focused on the meaning of the post-it note on the right.

Comment: So what does "beginning of baby boom" mean?

Comment: Just a guess, but the beginning of the "Baby Boomer" generation  (~1945) corresponds to the year the bomb was dropped on Hiroshima. One could also mark the dropping of the bomb as the beginning of the baby boomers, because "that's what ended the war" and motivated the beginning of a new generation. Since Oppenheimer worked extensively on the bomb, maybe it's suggesting Oppenheimer had a role in creating the new generation.